# Android SeekBar Minimum Value

Tags: java, android, android-view, seekbar

How to define a SeekBar's minimum value? Is this done in the XML layout or do I need to define it programatically?

Basically I need to change my minimum value from 0 to 0.2

Answer (score 127, accepted):

> How to define a SeekBar's minimum value?

You can't define the minimum value. It is `0`.

> Basically I need to change my minimum
>   value from 0 to 0.2

When you get the value, add `0.2` to it.

Comment: You should call `setProgress` too so the change is reflected on the UI - as Szabolcs Becze demonstrates in his answer.

Comment: @user1617737: No, you should not. His answer has nothing to do with the minimum value. The `SeekBar` represents the range from 0 to (max-min). To get the adjusted value, you add your desired minimum to the actual progress. Since the actual progress is already "reflected on the UI", there is nothing to change there.

Comment: OK, well that depends on how your labels are set up. I've just provided a complete answer which I think is the only correct way to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033135/android-seekbar-minimum-value/25239248#25239248

Comment: Set the MIN label with min value and set the MAX label with max value. In onProgressChanged(), Set your current value Label as progress+minValue.

Answer (score 25):

Here is what I use to get `android:max` for a max/min range for a `SeekBar`.

```
mSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    int progressChanged = minimumValue;

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        progressChanged = minimumValue+ progress;
    }
});
```

So you will get the range `minimum to minimum+max`;

To set the max value in xml, use `max=(desiredMax-min)`;

Comment: Yes I think this is the best approach. A SeekBar's units are just abstract values. You can simply adjust them in code to get the actual units you want, so I've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 11):

The min value must be 0 for the SeekBar object in Java (i.e., it cannot be changed), but this is how to get the required look and performance.

Suppose you want your min to be 5 and your max to be 100...

Therefore, you have a range of 95, so you would need to set up the SeekBar with a maximum value of `95`.

If your seekbar has UI labels, you would make them `5` (min) and `100` (max).

So, the layout XML would be something like...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sampleSizeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/batchDurationSecsLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sample_size" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sampleSizeSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="95" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="100" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So **now** you can introduce the `5` correction, like this...

```
final SeekBar sampleSizeSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sampleSizeSeekBar);
final int sampleSizeSeekBarCorrection = 5; //e.g., 95 <--> 100
int realValueFromPersistentStorage = appObj.getSampleSize(); //Get initial value from persistent storage, e.g., 100
sampleSizeSeekBar.setProgress(realValueFromPersistentStorage - sampleSizeSeekBarCorrection); //E.g., to convert real value of 100 to SeekBar value of 95.
sampleSizeSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    int val = sampleSizeSeekBar.getProgress();

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        val = progress + sampleSizeSeekBarCorrection; //e.g., to convert SeekBar value of 95 to real value of 100
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        try {
            appObj.saveSampleSize(val); //Save real value to persistent storage, e.g., 100
            appObj.makeToast("Sample size set to " + val);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error saving sample size", e);
            appObj.makeToast("Error saving sample size: " + e);
        }
    }
});
```

This solution will give your seekbar the correct min, max and scale on the UI, and the position of the control won't 'jump' to the right if the user slides it all the way to the left.

Answer (score 9):

Basically I have added the size+10 which will automatically set the min to 10 you can change yours to set it which min. value.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    int siz = size + 10;
    txtViewFontSize.setTextSize(siz);

    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(siz), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Answer (score 6):

My solution which works fine for me is:

```
    @Override 
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (progress <= SOME_LIMIT) {
        seekBar.setProgress(SOME_LIMIT);
    } else {
       // DO SOMETHING
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

In **api versions >=26** you can now add `min` xml attribute to SeekBar:

`android:min="0.2"`

Answer (score 4):

**You can not set progress in float because seekbar.getProgress() always returns integer value. Following code will set textview value to 0.2 if seekbar value is 0. you can change minimumVal according to your requirement.**

```
int minimumVal = 0;

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {


                if (progress >= minimumVal) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                    textView.setText(progress);
                } else {
                    seekBar.setProgress(minimumVal);
                    textView.setText("0.2");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

I created this simple library, it's not much, but it can save you some time.

https://github.com/joaocsousa/DoubleSeekBar

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this way:

int yourMinProgress = 10;

```
private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener onSeekBarChangeListener =
    new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {

            if (progress < yourMinProgress) {
                seekBar.setProgress(10);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i did this with Kotlin:

```
view.controlTextSize.setOnClickListener {

        textSizeControl.textSizeControlSlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{

            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                var progress = progress
                if (progress < 10){
                    progress = 10
                    seekBar?.progress = progress
                }

                view.content.textSize = progress.toFloat()
                prefs.edit().putFloat("ContentTextSize", progress.toFloat()).apply()
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
        })
        textSizeControl.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me fine!!!

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
seekBar.setMax(100);
seekBar.setProgress(40);
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);

SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
        if(progress <= 40){
            seekBar.setProgress(40);
        }
        if(progress >= 40) {
            pgr_status.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to set `seekBar` **minimum value**, just set set your `setOnSeekBarChangeListener` like this:

```
int minimumValue = 10; // your minimum value
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        // you can set progress value on TextView as usual
        txtProgress.setText(String.valueOf(progress));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        if(seekBar.getProgress() < minimumValue)
            seekBar.setProgress(minimumValue);

    }
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `com.android.support:preference-v7`, `SeekBarPreference` already has a method `setMin(int)`.

Just call that in `onCreatePreferences()` of your `PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

XML values will still be ignored on API < 26 but setting it programatically, works.