# Android seekbar how to block dragging in range of progress value

Tags: android, seekbar

To make clear , i want to prevent dragging at 80% of max value also left margin 20% . Dragging range will be (from 20% to the 80%) .

I just need to know is it possible make it from existing method clear and easy.

screenshot

[image]

Comment: There is no method, why don't you want to use `onProgressChanged`? It is the way to do it

Comment: add view on top of the seekbar and set it to clickable=true also use linearlayout to get the 20%

Comment: Alberto Méndez can you provide me example if you know it in the fly ...

Comment: @zombie If I'm not wrong that wouldn't't work because if you drag and move Android keeps the focus in the Seekbar so the view click wouldn't be reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `onProgressChanged` with a very basic calculations. If the min value is 0 and max value is 200 and we want to limit the first and last 20%. In the `onProgressChanged` method you just:

```
// I think this two variables should be out of the method
int limit = ((20 * 200) / 100);
int maxValue = seekBar.getMax();
if(seekBar.getProgress() >= (maxValue - limit)){
    seekBar.setProgress(maxValue);
}else if(seekBar.getProgress() <= limit){
    seekBar.setProgress(limit);
}
```

This has been done on the fly, it isn't tested and probably there is something wrong, but that is the idea

Comment: only need to remove minValue no need at all . in line :  seekBar.setProgress(minValue); must be  seekBar.setProgress(limit);

Comment: Yes, you are right, and the same to the `else if ` condition, if i'm not wrong

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033135/android-seekbar-minimum-value) regarding

> You can't define the minimum value. It is 0.

If you want to set maximum value you can do it

**by xml**

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="your_max_value"/>
```

**using java**

```
seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar_id);
seekBar.setMax(your_max_value);
```