# Call Requires API Level 26 Current Min is 15

Tags: android, progress-bar

I Am Trying To Add Horizintal PrograssBar But When I Set ADD (setMin)To Progress Bar It Shows Error,IKnow I Can Change min API but I Am trying Another Solution.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setMin(0);
```

Comment: Didnt Get you where it is?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479842/seekbar-setmin-require-at-least-api-26-in-android. 
The setMin(0) was added in api 26 so you need to add custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**setMin()** method was added in API level 26.

You can limit your **ProgressBar** Minimum value manually like this:

```
Int min = 10//your desired min value
if (progressBar.getProgress<min){
       progressBar.setProgress(min)
        }
```