# How to set Minimum progress seekbar?

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

i have this code to make some editor text and custom font size with seekbar, how to make a minimum value for int progres seekbar?

```
seekerFont.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        fontsize.setText(""+ progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set minimum or maximum progress

[image]

```
eekerFont.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){   

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

//TODO My code goes here

int CurrentLevel = eekerFont.getProgress();
if (CurrentLevel < 30) CurrentLevel = 30;
eekerFont.setProgress(CurrentLevel);

}

public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

}

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
boolean fromUser){
}});
```

In XML Also you can set

```
android:progress="10"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eekerFont.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    int progressChanged = minimumValue;

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        progressChanged = minimumValue+ progress;
    }
});
```

Link: [Android SeekBar Minimum Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033135/android-seekbar-minimum-value)

Answer (score 1):

Another better way is to do with little logic, For example you want to set values between 50 to 100. Then Do like this

```
seekBar.setMax(50);
int selectedProgress = seekBar.getProgress() + 50; // or in change listener
```